# Is there anything like rubygems.org for scala libraries

Tags: scala, sbaz

I notice there is an sbaz tool that seems to have similar functionality to the ruby gem tool but I don't see any community site like gemcutter.org / rubygems.org. Is there something like this around.

There are 1084 repositories on github with scala in them. I'm surprised I can't find some centralized package management utility. Perhaps I'm just googling the wrong keywords.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The closest equivalent is probably http://scala-tools.org which maintains a Maven (ivy, sbt, etc) repository of most of the best-known packages.

Comment: There's also Scala Bazaars, which is installed as part of the Scala distribution, but isn't used anywhere near as much as Maven/Ivy/sbt via scala-tools.org.

Comment: Sounds like a project ready to be started. I really like the self publishing aspect of ruby gems. Start a new project, push it to rubygems.org then the whole world can use it.

Comment: Having just looked for this today and coming across this question, it appears Scaladex is the place to go: https://index.scala-lang.org/

Answer (score 2):

Scala Tools appears to no longer be functional as of this writing. It says:

> We are no longer providing any support for scala-tools.org.

Instead, it is suggested to use https://oss.sonatype.org/

Answer (score 1):

As Kris said, http://scala-tools.org is the closest thing so far.  We're working on improving the site, and will be enabling "static project sites" shortly.   There's also http://implicit.ly/ which aims to be the standard new source for published releases.