# Kotlin Multiplatform: Is there anything like rubygems.org, pub.dev, npm for Kotlin Multiplatform libraries?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

Is there a website that maintains a list of Kotlin Multiplatform libraries?

I came across a few sources, but they are not official:

- https://libs.kmp.icerock.dev/
- https://github.com/AAkira/Kotlin-Multiplatform-Libraries

But is there any official listing like Pub.dev (Dart), NPM (Javascript), RubyGems.org (Ruby)?

---

*This question is very similar to "[Is there anything like rubygems.org for scala libraries [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3435329/816416)" but for Kotlin Multiplatform.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, up to now the "official" one is the

https://libs.kmp.icerock.dev/

that is linked in the official page https://kotlinlang.org/lp/mobile/ecosystem/